# comparison within loop while maintaining value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python program that
1. compares the first and last letter of a word
2. tell whether the words inputted to the program are in alphabetical order

e.g.) alaska baobab cadillac => would pass
e.g.) alaska baobab greg => would not pass

my code is shown below

```
num_words = int(input())

while num_words > 0:
    my_word = str(input())
    num_words -= 1

    alphabet_order = ord(my_word[0].lower())

    if my_word[0].lower() != my_word[-1].lower() or alphabet_order != ord(my_word[0].lower()):
        print(my_word)
        break
    alphabet_order += 1

    if alphabet_order == ord('z') + 1:
        alphabet_order = ord('a')

else:
    print('no mistake')
```

Hi everyone on stack.

I am pretty new to programming and I am starting to find assigning variables within a loop very cumbersome.

It seems like my variable alphabet_order keeps getting renewed every time when the loop takes in a new input.

What would be a great way to steadily increase the alphabet_order variable by 1 while only renewing `ord(my_word[0])` every loop?

Comment: `alaska baobab greg` is alphabetic order. Did you get your example wrong, or did you mean something other than alphabetic?

Comment: @Duncan I think OP might mean literally Alphabetical order as in the next letter in the alphabet should have a word. Skipping `c,d,e,f` before hitting `greg` breaks it.

Comment: @MoovingRawr is correct. I am trying to write a conditional statement that recognizes breakage in alphabetical order

Comment: You can remove that part already `or alphabet_order != ord(my_word[0].lower()` because it's equivalent to `or False` by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few notes, `while` loops are good for when you don't know how many times you are going to loop. `for` loops are good for when you know how many items you are looping. In this case we have a known number of words we are to check so using a `for` loop makes more sense. This way we don't need to take an input on telling us how many words we expect.

Also your code wasn't dealing with the words you were dealing with the sentence, so instead you should `split()` your input by the space to get a `list` of the words to operate on. `for` loops can iterate through a list which is useful for us.

Note that `for` loops also can take an `else`, the `else` section runs after the `for` loop is finished all the elements it's iterating through and we know that if the `for` is finish all the words in the list, then the `else` section will kick in. If we break out, then the `else` doesn't run.

The rest you more or less had it, just need a starting `ord('a')` would have made life easier.

```
my_word = input() #take a sentence such as alaska baobab cadillac 
current_ord = ord('a')
for each in my_word.split(' '):
    if each[0].lower() != each[-1].lower() or current_ord != ord(each[0].lower()):
        print(f"bad word {each}")
        break
    current_ord += 1

    if current_ord == ord('z') + 1:
        current_ord = ord('a')

else:
    print('no mistake')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful to you. Instead of initializing it inside the loop, declare it outside the loop and assign it differently based on the conditions.

*Tip*: having `while num_words > 0` is redundant because it will terminate automatically when it hits `0` as it is treated as `False`. And there is no need to convert `int` to a `str` type as it is `str` by default.

```
num_words = int(input("Enter a number"))

alphabet_order = None

while num_words:
    my_word = input("Enter a word")
    num_words -= 1

    if alphabet_order is None: # happens only once
        alphabet_order = ord(my_word[0].lower())

    if ord(my_word[0].lower()) >= alphabet_order:
        print('ok')
        alphabet_order = ord(my_word[0].lower()) # update alphabet_order
    else:
        print('not ok EXITING')
        break # closing loop
```